# Como bloquear datas específicas em um campo de entrada "date" com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou enfrentando dificuldades ao tentar bloquear datas específicas em um campo de entrada de tipo "date" em um formulário HTML. Minha situação é a seguinte:

Recebo uma lista de datas aleatórias do backend, algumas das quais podem ser passadas e outras futuras.
Quero garantir que o usuário não possa selecionar nenhuma dessas datas na interface.
Atualmente, tenho um código JavaScript que dispara um alerta de erro quando o usuário seleciona uma data indisponível. No entanto, acredito que não seja prático para o usuário tentar várias datas até encontrar uma disponível.

Exemplo: a lista com datas indisponiveis é (18/10/2023, 21/10/2023, 22/10/2023, 02/11/2023). No input do tipo date o usuario nao conseguiria selecionar essas data, algo parecido com o min e max só que podendo desabilitar as datas que estao na minha variavel/base de dados.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

É possível fazer o contrário, oferecer uma lista de datas possíveis como um autocomplete:

```html
<label for="date">Data:</label>
<input list="date-list" id="date" type="date" />

<datalist id="date-list">
  <option value="2023-08-19"></option>
  <option value="2023-08-20"></option>
  <option value="2023-08-21"></option>
</datalist>
```

Dependendo das datas, também pode desabilitar usando o atributo `step`, além do `min` e `max`:

```html
<label for="date">Data:</label>

<input type="date" id="date" value="2023-08-22" min="2023-08-01" max="2023-08-31" step="7" />
```

Mas, a melhor solução, provavelmente seria usar alguma biblioteca que crie esse campo customizado e ofereça o suporte a desabilitar as datas, por exemplo:

- https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled
- https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/forms/date-picker/#disable-dates

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu nao sabia que tinha isso no bootstrap. Testei aqui e funcionou!!